# How do we enable quick launcher and Min,max button in MATE (CentOS)?

Tags: centos, gnome, mate-desktop

I have installed MATE desktop environment in my CentOS (version 7.5 x64). But there is no quick launcher 'applications' button and also my VS code installation doesn't have min,max,close buttons.

I have used below command to install MATE desktop.

```
yum -y groupinstall "MATE Desktop"
```

What is wrong? [image]

In Gnome 3 desktop, 'application' button shown as below. how to enable 'application' button in MATE?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please open a terminal and run `mate-panel --reset` if that does not work run

`mate-menu --clean & mate-menu --clear & mate-menu --reset` 
to revert the menu config file to it's original state.

You can find a copy in `/etc/xdg/menus/mate-applications.menu/`

Now I couldn't find a good way to avoid rebooting, to restart the desktop environment.

What I found indicated to either kill your X or light-dm application to reboot desktop environment.

If you still do not have the menu visible please share what is in your `/etc/xdg/menus/mate-applications.menu` file as well as any output.

Please report if this issue exists if you create an other user and log into mate as the new user.

As a temp work around you can try `brisk-menu`, which comes highly recommended as a mate menu.

The Min Max window error is directly related to marco,

Comment: mate-menu --clean , bash:mate-menu : command not found